# Comment object is not being render in react || TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have been trying to solve this problem but couldn't find any solution. Here we go, the app has three components (1)`App` (2)`Menu` (3)`DishDetail` and the app is getting data from dishes files which is imported from shared folder in App component. The App component passes state to Menu and in Menu every thing is rendered perfectly and Menu also send data to DishDetail when card is clicked but problem is when i click one of the image card in Menu, the Card with description is rendered perfectly but the comment section is not rendered and when i remove the if statement in `renderComments()` function this gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined Error. What wrong did i do? Below i posted the code. Please Help

**App Component**

```
.....
import { DISHES } from "./shared/dishes";
import Menu from "./components/MenuComponent";
.....

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dishes: DISHES };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Menu Component**

```
.......
import DishDetail from "./DishDetailComponent";

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedDish: null };
  }

  onDishSelect(dish) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
  }

  render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{menu}</div>
        <DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

**DishDetail**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";

class DishDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderDish(dish) {
    if (dish != null) {
      return (
        <Card>
          <CardImg src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }

  renderComments(comments) {
    if (comments != null) {
      return comments.map((comment) => {
        return <div>{comment.comment}</div>;
      });
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderDish(this.props.dish)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderComments(this.props.comments)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DishDetail;
```

**Data File**

```
export const DISHES = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Uthappizza",
    image: "assets/images/uthappizza.png",
    category: "mains",
    label: "Hot",
    price: "4.99",
    description:
      "A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.",
    comments: [
      {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z",
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        rating: 4,
        comment:
          "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Zucchipakoda",
    image: "assets/images/zucchipakoda.png",
    category: "appetizer",
    label: "",
    price: "1.99",
    description:..............
...................
................}}
```

**Update: i fixed the issue by doing some changes.**

**In Menu component:**

```
// Old Code(Not working)
<DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />

//Replace with new code
<DishDetail selectedDish={this.state.selectedDish} />
```

**In DishDetail component:**

```
// Old Code(Not Working)
renderComments(comments) {
    if (comments != null) {
      return comments.map((comment) => {
        return <div>{comment.comment}</div>;
      });
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderDish(this.props.dish)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderComments(this.props.comments)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
//Replace with new code
renderComments(dish) {
    if (dish != null) {
      return dish.comments.map((com) => {
        return <div>{com.comment}</div>;
      });
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderDish(this.props.selectedDish)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          {this.renderComments(this.props.selectedDish)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use directly DISHES like that

```
    const menu = DISHES.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });
```